# Why can't round correctly using Math.round?

Tags: android, kotlin, rounding

Why can't I round correctly this:

```
val solution = Math. round(iDouble * 10.00) / 10.00
```

Debugger says:

```
iDouble = 118.64300000000001
solution = 118.6
```

Comment: The output is correct. What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see what is wrong with that. Here is the explanantion.

118.64300000000001d * 10L = 1186.43d

Math.round will return the number rounded to the integer part as an long.

Math.round(1186.43d) = 1186L.

1186L / 10.00d = 118.6d

So it looks fine to me. Keep in mind that dividing by a double/float will result in a double/float.